# How can I compile with the "kotlin.test" dependency on the commandline?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

High Folks,
I started to learn Kotlin and I ran into a dependency issue for "kotlin.test" on my Linux machine which I don't know to overcome:

kotlinc first_unit_test.kt -> fails

On the Kotlin webpage it is mentioned that "kotlin.test" is
under the hood, but I don't know how include and activate
it on the command line.

```
first_unit_test.kt:1:15: error: unresolved reference: test                           
import kotlin.test.Test
              ^
first_unit_test.kt:2:15: error: unresolved reference: test
import kotlin.test.assertTrue
              ^
first_unit_test.kt:6:3: error: unresolved reference: Test
        @Test
  ^
first_unit_test.kt:9:3: error: unresolved reference: assertTrue
                assertTrue("Hello" in "Hello World!")
  ^
```

Even if I include the runtime I get the same error :-(

```
kotlinc first_unit_test.kt -include-runtime -d first_unit.jar
```

Here the very small test program:

```kotlin
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertTrue

class first_unit_test {

        @Test
        fun testHello()
        {
                assertTrue("Hello" in "Hello World!")
        }
}
```

I also tried the "-cp" switch, but I couldn't get it to work.
Actually I want to compile and later I want to run those unit test,
and I have no clue how to make them run either ...

Comment: If you're learning Kotlin, you should probably use Gradle to manage your dependencies and your test runs. If your goal is to really dig into the CLI compiler and the classpath mecanism it's a different story, but it really depends on your goal here. Apart from very basic toy programs to demonstrate how compilation works, real life projects mostly use build tools like Gradle or Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I made some progress:

first I copied
kotlin-test.jar
kotlin-test-junit.jar
into the build folder and
I changed the build command:

```
kotlinc -cp ".:./kotlin-test.jar:./kotlin-test-junit.jar" first_unit_test.kt -include-runtime -d first_unit.jar
```

Now I have a new error for which I do not have a clue:

```
first_unit_test.kt:6:3: error: this class does not have a constructor
        @Test
  ^
```

Why do I have to provide a constructor?

```kotlin
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertTrue

class first_unit_test {

        @Test
        fun testHello()
        {
                assertTrue("Hello" in "Hello World!")
        }
}
```

Comment: If you're writing a question, you should either update your existing question or create a new question. Creating an answer is not appropriate for this